# transfer item from circle moving inside another circle without 180 degree rotation

Tags: geometry, circles

I am aware of the [circle illusion](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2017/05/07/the-circular-motion-illusion-explained-mathematically-sunday-puzzle/) that the point moves in a straight direction [a circle of r = R/2 rolling inside another ciecle]. I tried to make practical use of this in moving an item from one end to the other end of the diameter but I quickly noticed that the item will be rotated by 180 degrees at the other end.

Is there a way and/or use some different r in which the item will not be rotated when it reaches another end of the bigger outermost circle.

It is important to note, I do not want to move the items from one circle to another possible circle inside the bigger circle. I also do not care if the entire path of the item is a straight line, the important thing is it should reach the exact opposite end of the bigger outermost circle.

Comment: Using a circle r/4 should do the trick.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to help. When the item reaches the other end, it is rotated by 180.

Comment: After a second thought - rotation is inherit in the Forced motion as defined. To get to the other end with this RIGID structure means that the only "places" where the device is not rotated, means that the internal circle need to keep the device at the other end - further from the external circuit. If the device is not rotating with the internal circle than you could have it not being rotated at 180.